# golang crane SDK's Push return unauthorized error when docker login is done with golang docker SDK's RegistryLogin

Tags: docker, go

I'm trying to replace all my cmd.Exec() function calls with the golang SDK for crane and docker. I want to push an image to a remote registry so I logged in to that registry with [RegistryLogin()](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/docker/docker/client#Client.RegistryLogin) function and pushing the image with crane SDK's [Push](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-containerregistry/pkg/crane#Push) function. But I'm getting unauthorized error. How do I resolve this situation ?

Thanks